# Помогите разобраться с работой функции на python

Tags: python

Нужна помощь. В программе на python встретилась вот такая функция, что она делает и как с ней работать?

```
def funk(sepend):
    return [sepend[0][0][0], sepend[0][1][0]]
```

Comment: На будущее: в панели управления, когда задаёте вопрос, есть специальные скобки(`{ }`) с их помощью можно правильно оформить код) Попробуйте сами

Answer (score 3):

Данная функция получает трёхмерный список/кортеж и потом возвращает данные из этого списка под нужными индексами.

Вот пример такого списка:

```
sepend = [
           [
             [1,2,3],
             [4,5,6],
             [7,8,9]
           ],
           [
             [10,11,12],
             [12,14,15],
             [16,17,18]
           ],
           [
             [19,20,21],
             [22,23,24],
             [25,26,27]
           ]
         ]
```

В данном примере я могу вытянуть лбое значение с помощью такой записи: `sepend[i][k][m]`, где `i,k и m` это нужные вам индексы. Например: `sepend[0][0][2]` выведет мне `3`
Пояснение: `i=0, k=0, m=2` это индексы, чтобы Нам правильно понять какие нужны индексы, добавим `+1` к каждому индексу и получим `i=1, k=1, m=3`. Следовательно, нам нужно взять первый список, из первого списка взять тоже первый список и оттуда вытянуть число, стоящее на 3 месте. Это будет 3.

В вашем случае, это будут числа 1 и 10 из моего примера

В конечном итоге, функция с помощью `return` передаёт новый список(`[]`), но всего с двумя значениями и он одномерный. На выходе вы получите: `[1, 10]`

Более подробно [тут](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/2d_arrays/)

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, но я бы ещё добавил, что в `return` полученные значения собираются в список из двух элементов с помощью `[]`. ИМХО сомнения вызвали именно квадратные скобки после `return`.

Comment: @V-Mor, не заметил их До этого код был неправильно оформлен Ща добавлю)

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли.

Comment: @Hopman, обращайтесь

Также не забудьте отметить ответ галочкой. Это значит что на вопрос дан ответ, который помог, и другие пользователи форума будут уверены что вам больше не нужна помощь